# SQL query to format date datatype to exclude time

Tags: c#, sql, date

I'm trying to fill a listbox with dates from an SQL database when an account transaction is selected in another listbox. Right now the dates are displaying times as well as dates. I'm using a date datatype in my Date data table but i'm not sure how to format the date to exclude time.

```
 try
        {
            string query = "select a.Date from Date a inner join AccountTransaction act on" +
                " a.Id = act.DateId where act.AccountId = @AccountId";

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection);
            SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);

            using (sqlDataAdapter)
            {
                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountId", AccountList.SelectedValue);
                DataTable associatedDateTable = new DataTable();
                sqlDataAdapter.Fill(associatedDateTable);
                DateList.DisplayMemberPath = "Date";
                DateList.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
                DateList.ItemsSource = associatedDateTable.DefaultView;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is not having a format. It's just a date. If you want to show it in a specific way, you have to convert it.

```
select getdate()
```

gives you: 2019-01-23 12:51:03.663

```
select CONVERT (varchar(10), getdate(), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

gives you 23/01/2019

```
string query = "select CONVERT (varchar(10), a.Date, 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY] from Date a inner join AccountTransaction act on" +
                " a.Id = act.DateId where act.AccountId = @AccountId";
```